# woocommerce get_available_variations() stripping slashes

Tags: woocommerce

I want to display variations in a list format and i've implemented the code below

```
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();

        foreach ($variations as $key => $value) {

            echo "<li><span data-slug='".implode('/', $value['attributes'])."'>".esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', str_replace("-"," ",implode(' ', $value['attributes'])) ) ) ."</span></li>";
        }
```

The problem is the website i'm working on has attributes such as; `30/50`, `40/50`.  When they are returned, they are displayed without a slash so `3050`, `4050`.

How do i solve this so they include the slash?

Comment: I'm also facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You must replace each slash sign in the string with an HTML entity code. The code for a forward slash is:  `&#47;`